# ASP.NET Core issue with Update record in Sql

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

I am using ASP.NET Core and SQL Server . When trying to update a record in the database I am getting this following error message:

> Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 39 row(s).

I will past the code below, but the part that is very confusing is that the "where" statement is using the tables primary key -- there is no way that there is more than 1 record with the same key -- which I verified several times.

```
using (var transaction = _ctx.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    var sql = @"Update [Policies] SET  DateInvalid = @DateTimeNow Where EntryNum = @EntryNum";
    _ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql,
             new SqlParameter("@DateTimeNow", DateTime.Now),
             new SqlParameter("@EntryNum", existing.EntryNum) );
    _ctx.SaveChanges();
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run the query directly in MSSMS? Does it update the same number of rows?

Comment: UPDATE [dbo].[Policies]
 SET DateInvalid = GetDate() WHERE EntryNum = 8090. This works no problem from MSSMS. I am starting to suspect that it  is one of this misreported errors that's masking the real issue.

Comment: I found the issue. I did not have the [Key] attribute set in the class that I used for the update. On the datatable, the field was the key but by not having it on the class I ran into all sorts of trouble. Unfortunately the error messages were not very clear.

Comment: It's not obvious here but the class is used within the context definition (_ctx)